# how to display a meta field on product detail page in shopify?

Tags: php, shopify

i have a created meta filed using the shopify API call like this:

```
'POST', '/admin/products/1328/metafields.json', array("metafield" =>           
   array('namespace'=>'inventory',                                                                                              
         'key'=>'warehouse',
         'value'=>"some text here",
         'value_type'=>'string')));
```

But now I want to show this on product detail page how can I achieve this? Or where it will be displayed on the product detail page in Shopify.

Can anyone (who has a eCommerce shop on any other system but not on shopify) can see these meta fields?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
{% for variant in product.variants %}
  // to display the variant metafields use {{resource.metafields.namespace.key}}
  {{ variant.metafields.ShippingWeight.shipping_weight }}
{% endfor %}
```

SOURCE : [How to Display a Metafield in Shopify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15141652/how-to-display-a-metafield-in-shopify)

Comment: can't i do this with shopify api or Api doesn't provide the functionality?

Comment: let say i create a meta field of "comments" and it displays on the product detail page, customer provide some comments and then the next time any other customer views that product s/he should be displayed the older comments.

Comment: You must make changes in your theme.

Answer (score 2):

```
{{ product.metafields.inventory.warehouse }}
```

use this line in product.liquid page.
Let me know if it doesn't work.