# Script tag is not showing anything on frontstore in shopify

Tags: php, shopify

I have created an script tag using shopify Api

```
    $src = "http://localhost/shopifyplugin/shopify.js";
    $script = $sc->call('POST', '/admin/script_tags.json', array(
            "script_tag"=> array(
                "event"=>"onload", "src"=>"$src"
             )));
```

The js file code:

```
console.log("Coming here...");
alert("coming here...");
jQuery("form[action='/cart/add']").each(function() {
  console.log("I'm in product page");
});
```

But, on the store it is not showing any thing. Do I need to include jquery if yes then in which file should i need to include, I am creating the script tag in index.php file.

Comment: Yes if you using jQuery, you need to include jQuery. And you can include it anywhere before calling any of it's function.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16271738/shopify-displaying-some-extra-information-on-product-detail-page http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16230835/how-to-display-a-meta-field-on-product-detail-page-in-shopify http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16162699/how-to-make-an-app-in-shopify-with-php-step-by-step

Comment: i have created script tag, but it is not showing on any front page of store.

Comment: @SyedAli can you please explain how you add a script tag i am getting this error
Warning: Closure::call() expects parameter 1 to be object, string given
Or can you refer some tutorial from where i can get help , i am stucked in this point. thanks

Answer (score -1):

Try http://support.shopify.com/. You'll most likely get better support there.

Also, http://support.shopify.com/#stq=javascript&stp=1 for javascript help :)

Comment: script tag is created and in my js file i'm just showing something on console but, nothing is showing on store front page.